# Why my table value is not showing up in django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I retrieve my table in views and when i tried to use it in template is is not showing anything.

This is my views file

```
def index(request):
    attendances = attendance.objects.all()
    return render(request, "salary/index.html", {'attendance': attendances})
```

and this is my template code

```
{% for attendances in attendance %}
    <th>{{attedances.id}}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

and this is my model

```
class attendance(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField
    staff_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    attendance = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Comment: It looks ok. Are there objects in your `attendance` model?

Comment: **Not** `<th>{{attedances.id}}</th>`, **but** `<th>{{attendances.id}}</th>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the spelling of *attendances*. So:

```
{% for attendances in attendance %}
    <th>{{attendances.id}}</th>
{% endfor %}
```